# display inline não funciona!

Tags: css

Gostaria que ficasse assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, só fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código css:

```
.ro{
text-align: center;
display: inline;
}
```

Código php:

```
    <div class="ro">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <p>_______________________________________</p>
        <p>Coordenador Pedagógico</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <p>_______________________________________</p>
        <p>Gestor</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem vária formas de resolver isso, vou te dar a que eu acho mais simples que é colocando as duas `div` de class `.ro` dentro de um *container* com `felx`. O flex vai fazer com que as duas `div` fiquem uma ao lado da outra, e com `justify-content: center;` vc  alinha tudo no centro

Veja o código:

```css
.ro{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ro col-4 text-center">
      <p>_______________________________________</p>
      <p>Coordenador Pedagógico</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ro col-4 text-center">
      <p>_______________________________________</p>
      <p>Gestor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado! Deu certo.

Comment: @wenermorais sem problemas amigo, boa sorte ai ;)